# Linux command for merging files using java not working

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to execute terminal command for merging two .csv files using java programme, my command is working fine at terminal but not working properly in java.

Below is my code :

```
String command = "awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}' /opt/test/*.csv >> /opt/test/output.csv";

    Process proc;
    int exitStatus;
    while (true) {
        try {
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            exitStatus = proc.waitFor();

            break;
        } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("inside exception" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    if (exitStatus != 0) {
        System.out.println("Problem occured");
    }
```

Comment: Try to read the error stream to see what happends. An example you find [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html)

Comment: I tried this and error is : invalid file path.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in java code but in Linux handling of files: you are directing output to a file which is considered as input right after creation.

Try this as command:

`awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}' /opt/test/*.csv >> /opt/test/output.txt ; mv /opt/test/output.txt /opt/test/output.csv`

Comment: Thanks for guidance, but if i try with particular file name i.e. file name where input file is not equal to output file. It wouldn't work.

Comment: Well if you need to concatenate *every* .csv file in another csv you can use "cat /opt/test/*.csv  >> /opt/test/output.txt && mv /opt/test/output.txt /opt/test/output.csv". This will work flawlessly on Linux bash. In fact command should be "/bin/bash -c \"cat /opt/test/*.csv  >> /opt/test/output.txt ; mv /opt/test/output.txt /opt/test/output.csv\""